# How can I write a generic Guice binding function?

Tags: java, generics, guice

How can I abstract the Option type in the below Guice binding code, substituting a generic parameter for `Option`?

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Option>> options = 
 new ArrayList<Class<? extends Option>>();
bindMultibinder(annotation, options);

public Key<Set<Option>> bindMultibinder(
 Named annotation, ArrayList<Class<? extends Option>> contents) {
   Multibinder<Option> options = 
    Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Option.class, annotation);
   for (Class<? extends Option> option : contents) {
      options.addBinding().to(option);
   }
   final Key<Set<Option>> multibinderKey = 
    Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Set<Option>>(){}, annotation);
   return multibinderKey;
}
```

Comment: The "generics equivalent" is in no way equivalent to your first example because at no point do you provide a means by which the compiler can know what the value is for T.

Comment: Sorry @DwB, but I don't think this is the case.  The compiler can and does correctly infer the correct type for T.  I surmise that it does so from the Class<T> superClass parameter in the bindMultibinder method.  Maybe you didn't see that parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Stuart McCulloch](https://plus.google.com/108081409801028235828) on Google Groups for answering:

> ^ the new TypeLiteral<...>(){} anonymous class trick only works when
>   the type parameter is known at compile time.
>
> If you need to build generic types at runtime you can use the
>   com.google.inject.util.Types utility class, for example:

```
final Key<Set<T>> multibinderKey =
    Key.get( Types.setOf( superClass ), annotation );
```

To get this to build correctly, I modified it as follows:

```
final Key<?> multibinderKey = Key.get(Types.setOf( superClass ), annotation);
```

So the complete generic method is:

```
public <T> Key<?> bindMultibinder(
 Named annotation, Class<T> superClass, ArrayList<Class<? extends T>> contents) {
   Multibinder<T> options = 
    Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), superClass, annotation);
   for (Class<? extends T> t : contents) {
      options.addBinding().to(t);
   }
   final Key<?> multibinderKey = Key.get(Types.setOf( superClass ), annotation);
   return multibinderKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `java.util.Set<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.`

Says to me that Guice `Key` doesn't support using Generics - you can only have something fully specified (i.e. with no unbound type parameters).

Comment: Thanks for interpreting the error; that makes sense.  I bet I need to use a Guice `TypeLiteral` to accomplish this.  I'll update with an answer if I fix it.