# How to bind a generic type using @Provides method in a Guice AbstractModule?

Tags: java, guice

E.g.

```
public final class SomeModule<T> extends AbstractModule {
  private final Class<T> clazz;
  public SomeModule(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  @Provides
  T getT(@ExternalAnnotation Any any) {
    Any payload = asset.get().getPayload();
    return payload.<T>unpack(clazz);
  }
}
```

This will result in an error:

```
T cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

Neither using TypeLiteral nor Key seems appropriate here, since I want the return type to still be of type T.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With type erasure, Guice will not have enough information from an instance of your module to determine what type you're binding.

Instead, accept a class literal and use it. This example keeps the generics, but if you don't need them for your use-case, you can drop them.

```
// Warning: Untested. Please revise if needed.
public final class SomeModule<T> extends AbstractModule {
  private Class<T> t;

  public SomeModule(Class<T> t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    // Uses a class instance rather than reflection, so this is fine.
    bind(t).toProvider(new Provider<T>() {
      // ... do stuff
    });
  }
}
```

See also:

- [How can I write a generic Guice binding function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672431/how-can-i-write-a-generic-guice-binding-function) (also [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-guice/R1SedgRwNzE/N7baUuZY8MsJ))
- [Have a common provider for subclasses using Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403119/have-a-common-provider-for-subclasses-using-guice)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and link to other examples!